# DSolve Difficulty to Make it work

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following equation:

$$\frac { 1 } { 2 } m \dot { x } ^ { 2 } + \frac { 1 } { 2 } k x ^ { 2 } = \frac { 1 } { 2 } k g _ { 0 } ^ { 2 }$$

with initial conditions: 
$x = 0$ and  $d x / d t = 0 \text { at } t = 0$

Now, I would like to calculate it with Mathematica:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
DSolve[{1/2*m*x'[t]^2 + 1/2*k*x[t]^2 - 1/2*k*g0^2 == 0, x[0] = 0, 
  x'[0] = 0}, x[t], t]
```

But it does not work. Any ideas what is wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: There are two problems: first, the initial conditions are specified with `==` (not `=`); then you have two initial conditions for a first order equation, and you cannot necessarily satisfy both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
DSolve[{1/2*m*x'[t]^2 + 1/2*k*x[t]^2 - 1/2*k*g0^2 == 0, x[0] == 0}, x[t], t]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :)